# "Column `distinctAlias.post_id` does not exist" Typeorm

Tags: sql, node.js, typescript, graphql, typeorm

I have a `posts` resolver which uses this logic to return posts:

```js
const qb = Post.createQueryBuilder('post')
            .select(['post.id AS id', 'post.createdAt AS id'])
            .addSelect(
                "json_build_object('id', user.id, 'username', user.username, 'email', user.email, 'createdAt', user.createdAt, 'updatedAt', user.updatedAt)",
                'creator'
            )

        if (req.session.userId)
            qb.addSelect((qb) => {
                return qb
                    .subQuery()
                    .select('updoot.value')
                    .from(Updoot, 'updoot')
                    .where('"userId" = :userId AND "postId" = post.id', {
                        userId: req.session.userId
                    })
            }, 'voteStatus')
        else qb.addSelect('null', 'voteStatus')

        qb.innerJoin('post.creator', 'user')
            .orderBy('post.createdAt', 'DESC')
            .take(realLimitPlusOne)

        if (cursor)
            qb.where('post.createdAt < :cursor', {
                cursor: new Date(parseInt(cursor))
            })

        qb.printSql()
        const posts = await qb.getRawAndEntities()
        console.log('posts: ', posts['raw'][0])

        return {
            posts: posts['raw'].slice(0, realLimit),
            hasMore: posts['raw'].length === realLimitPlusOne
        }
```

I want my data to be structured in this way:

```js
posts:  {
  id: 29,
  createdAt: 2023-02-07T06:53:39.453Z,
  creator: {
    id: 44,
    username: 'prashant',
    email: 'prashant@gmail.com',
    createdAt: '2023-02-06T13:02:11.717504',
    updatedAt: '2023-02-06T13:02:11.717504'
  },
  voteStatus: -1
}
```

But instead of `id` and `createdAt` I get `post_id` and `post_createdAt` key names which is not compatible with my graphql types. Even though I added the aliases for these columns I am getting:

```js
posts:  {
  post_id: 29,
  post_createdAt: 2023-02-07T06:53:39.453Z,
  creator: {
    id: 44,
    username: 'prashant',
    email: 'prashant@gmail.com',
    createdAt: '2023-02-06T13:02:11.717504',
    updatedAt: '2023-02-06T13:02:11.717504'
  },
  voteStatus: -1
}
```

Is there any problem with my code or should I create a mapping function which key names to appropriate ones?

Answer (score 0):

I also had a "Column 'distinctAlias._id' does not exist" error.
It was because I was not selecting the id in the query.
So it is not that the key names are not compatible, but that it has to allways select the id of an item and you are not selecting it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).